# formdata via ajax but got empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

https://jsfiddle.net/y8mm4u9o/

```js
$('.imageUp').change(function() {
  var ext = $(this).val().replace(/^.*\./, '').toLowerCase();

  if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
    alert('Only Image can be Upload!');
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this);
    console.log(formData);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo-picker">
  <div class="camera">
    <div class="lens"></div>
    <div class="grip"></div>
    <div class="moc"></div>
    <input type="file" class="imageUp" />
  </div>
  <div class="preview-card"><img src="" class="preview" /><span class="photo-title"></span></div>
</div>
```

Not sure this is the right way to send file via ajax to server, but so far I'm seeing formdata is empty in my chrome's console.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a form field to `this` as it is a DOM element. You need to retrieve the element's key value instead.

```js
$('.imageUp').change(function() {
  var ext = $(this).val().replace(/^.*\./, '').toLowerCase();

  if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
    alert('Only Image can be Upload!');
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[0]);
    console.log(formData);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the file data instead of this

```
$('.imageUp').change(function(e) {
  var ext = $(this).val().replace(/^.*\./, '').toLowerCase();

  if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']) == -1) {
    alert('Only Image can be Upload!');
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(formData);
  }
})
```